# i can not make some moudule in python

Tags: python

please give me some good example about moudule <os> in python.

thanks for your help.

Like the code example below

```
files = os.listdir("C:/Users/Total Guarantee/Desktop/")
print(files.count('homi.txt'))
os.remove("C:/Users/Total Guarantee/Desktop/x.txt")
```

Comment: I don't quite understand the question, can you elaborate? If you're in search of general information regarding the os module, the documentation is available here: https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html

If you're in search of help fpr a particular aspect/function of the os module let me know and I'd be glad to help. حظا موفقا يا صديقي

Comment: I just wanted some fun modules for Python.

Comment: If you're looking for general info, I'd recommend poking around through the documentation. Getting familar with the built-in modules such as OS, SYS, RE, SHUTIL, etc etc would be a great way to get familiar with python - and many people overlook them! However, Stackoverflow is geared towards very specific questions for particular problems - not much good for general information unfortunately. Here's a link that covers the built-in functions, should help you get started: https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html